# Partial orders with separable linear extensions

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Is the following consistent?

CH fails and there is a partial order $\preceq$ on $\omega_2$ such that for every $\alpha < \omega_2$, $(\alpha, \preceq)$ can be extended to a separable linear order $(\alpha, \preceq_{\alpha})$ but there is no separable linear order 
 extending $(\omega_2, \preceq)$.

This is related to an earlier question of Noah Schweber: [What kind of compactness does "expanding $\mathbb{R}$ by constants" have?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252407/what-kind-of-compactness-does-expanding-mathbbr-by-constants-have)

Comment: Do you know what happens if you try to unify the linearizations of the $\alpha$-suborders by using a uniform ultrafilter on $\omega_2$? In other words, fix a separable linearization for each $\alpha$, and then say $\beta\lhd\gamma$ if $\beta$ is below $\gamma$ in the $\alpha$-linearization for $U$-almost all $\alpha$ above. This gives a linear order, but I don't think it has to be separable.